# Create a non-hdfs csv from spark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a non-hdfs .csv file using a spark DataFrame. How can do it ?

The purpose of this non-hdfs .csv file is to use read_csv() on it and load it back to a pandas DataFrame.

I tried using toPandas() but I have 45 million records in my spark DataFrame and its very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to write to s3, there are a couple of ways to do it:

1. Use Parquet which is columnar optimized

Assuming your dataframe is df:

```
# Spark takes care of everything here, but you will have multiple files in the folder
df.write.parquet('s3a://path/filename')
```

2. Use csv which is more traditional and row formatted

```
# Spark takes care of everything here, and you will have a single file in the end
df.repartition(1).write\
.option('header', 'True')\
.format('csv')\
.save('s3a://path/')
```

Comment: Not s3, I will like to write it to local node on a Hadoop Cloudera-cluster

Answer (score 0):

If you have 45 million records you will likely need to create a set of csv files which spark will do automatically.  Depending on where you want to save the data the path will vary.  For example if you wanted to write to S3 you would provide a path like this.

> df.write.csv("s3://my-bucket/path/to/folder/")

You may also want to manually repartition the data before writing to get an exact number of output files.